# golang what's the different between return []*TreeNode{} and return []*TreeNode{nil}

Tags: pointers, go, recursion

I'm new to golang and confused by the following,

```golang
type TreeNode struct {
    Val   int
    Left  *TreeNode
    Right *TreeNode
}

func test() []*TreeNode {

    return []*TreeNode{}
}

func test1() []*TreeNode {

    return []*TreeNode{nil}
}
```

I'm trying to write a recursion func on TreeNode, however, if I used the `test` style to represent the leaf node, I will get an empty TreeNode slice from the caller func.

If I use the `test1` to represent the leaf node, then the behaviour is what I want.

I feel that for the `test1`, it's giving me a point to an empty TreeNode, however, the `test` code, is giving me a point to `nil`... I'm not sure if I'm getting this right or not. Can you please point me the correct terms or concepts to dig, it will be great.

In addition, if you can let me know more about the underline logic, it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One slice contains a `nil` and one doesn't, exactly as you wrote it. I imagine the question has something to do with code you haven't included here.

Comment: One returns an empty slice, one returns a slice with a single `nil` element.

Answer (score 1):

This returns an empty slice:

```
return []*TreeNode{}
```

This returns a slice containing one element, and that element is a nil pointer:

```
return []*TreeNode{nil}
```

None of these give you a `TreeNode` though. The second one gives you a TreeNode pointer that is nil. How you interpret these depends on the rest of the code, but I doubt either is really what you want, since none can have the `val` field.